# Function composition: $\Phi$ locally Lipschitz map and $f \in AC([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, absolute-continuity

Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a locally Lipschitz map, i.e. a map for which for every compact set $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ there exists a constant $c$ such that $|\Phi(x)-\Phi(y)|\leq c|x-y|$ for every $x, y \in K$.

Prove that if $f \in AC([0, 1])$ then $\Phi ◦f \in AC([0, 1])$.

**My idea:**

$\Phi$ is locally Lipschitz, so $\Phi\in Lip([0,1])$ hence:
\begin{equation}
\exists L>0 \quad s.t. \quad |\Phi(x)-\Phi(y)|\leq L|x-y|
\end{equation}
Furthermore, $f \in AC([0, 1])$, so
\begin{equation}
\forall \epsilon>0 \qquad \exists\delta=\delta(\epsilon) \quad s.t. \quad \sum(b_i-a_i)<\delta \Rightarrow \sum|f(b_i)-f(a_i)|<\epsilon
\end{equation}
Fix $\epsilon>0$. I have:
\begin{equation}
\sum |\Phi(f(b_i))-\Phi(f(a_i))|\leq \sum L|f(b_i)-f(a_i)|
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\leq nL\sum |f(b_i)-f(a_i)|
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\leq nL\epsilon
\end{equation}

Comment: The inequality $|\Phi(x)-\Phi(y)|\leq L|x-y|$ only holds for $x,y\in[0,1]$. Although $f\in AC([0,1])$, we do not neccessarily have that the function values $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are in $[0,1]$. You need to make an argument about the function values $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ for $x,y\in[0,1]$ being in some compact set, then apply Lipschitz continuity to that compact set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is absolutely continuous it is therefore also continuous. Then, since $[0,1]$ is a compact set we have that $f([0,1])$ is a compact set as well, i.e. $\exists m,M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $m\leq f(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Since $\Phi$ is locally Lipschitz, it is Lipschitz on the set $[m,M]$ with constant $L$. Now you can use the rest of your proof, with the justification for,

$$|\Phi(f(b_i))-\Phi(f(a_i))|\leq L|f(b_i)-f(a_i)|$$

being the above.